# How to Delay batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have looked around every forum going for this and the two solutions that are suggested are to either use Ping or use timeout. I am using the timeout, but I have the same issue with ping.

The issue I am having is that if I use the timeout command at the very beginning it works fine but if I sandwich the timeout between two calls for instance, the timeout is completely ignored.

```
    CALL C:\Progra~1\Folder\Batchscript1.bat

    timeout /t 30 /nobreak

    CALL C:\Progra~1\Folder\Batchscript2.bat
```

The two batch scripts are both sending an email. With the set up above, this batch finishes almost instantly (should timeout for 30 seconds) and sends both emails successfully.

When I look at what is happening in the batch, I am getting the following error:
"timeout is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Again this doesn't make sense too me seeing as the timeout works just fine in the below batch.

```
    timeout /t 30 /nobreak

    CALL C:\Progra~1\Folder\Batchscript2.bat
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I tried it and it works here. I sandwiched the timeout between two batch file calls. If this is XP, I think you need the XP Resource Kit.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html

Comment: Are you changing any path or environment variables inside your call to Batchscript1bat? Can you give us some insight in what is happening in Batchscript1.bat?

Comment: "timeout" is not in default XP commands. Ping is more universal. You can use 3rd part tools to make a delay in your script. Something simple in C++. e.g. "delay.exe seconds 30"

Comment: What happens when you extend the call to timeout with the fully qualified path? "%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 30 /nobreak

Comment: Ok,I fixed it. I resolved the issue by putting C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe instead of just timeout.

Comment: just saw your comment Marwie. Fully qualifying the path worked thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there must be something in your call to Batchscript1.bat which is having an impact on your call to timeout.exe.
Try extending the call of timeout.exe with the fully qualified path:

```
 "%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 30 /nobreak
```

However, keep in mind, that you may have only treated a symptom. The cause of the issue may still affect your second script.

If you are not required to use a variable of batchscript1 in batchscript2 you should consider using `setlocal` and `endlocal` around the batchscript1 call.

Comment: There is a danger with this solution. If, as it seems probable, `batchscript1` changes `PATH` then any dependence of `batchscript2` on `path` may cause problems. A setlocal/endlocal bracket around the `call` of `batchscript1` may cure this - unless `batchscript2` relies on a returned variable from `batchscript 1`